# Checking if a item exists withot being case sensitive

Tags: python-3.x, ponyorm

Is possible to check if an element exists without being case sensitive without using queries with PonyORM?

I have a table with the definition:

```
Client(id: int PRIMARY KEY, name: Text, location: Text)
```

So, it would be something like:

```
Client.exists(name='stackoverflow'.upper())
```

This does not work as it only converts into case a part of the comparison, but not the contents from the Database.

I mean the equivalent to the query:

```
SELECT * From Client WHERE UPPER(Client.name) = UPPER('stackoverflow')
```

But using the already existing functionality in ponyORM with the exists() method.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution using Lambda functions.

Writing this:

```
Client.exists(lambda: str(c.name).upper() == 'stackoverflow'.upper())
```